# JBoss HornetQ JMX access

Tags: jboss

We have HornetQ messaging running inside JBoss. From a remote VM we are unable to connect using JMXURL.

HornetQ settings (hornet1 configuration.xml):

```
<jmx-management-enabled>true</jmx-management-enabled>
```

JBoss settings

> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3000 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false

From a remote JVM none of these URLs work:

- service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:8070/jmxrmi
- service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:8007/jmxconnector

Comment: Which version of JBoss is it?

Comment: did you try connecting locally?

Answer (score 1):

As for JBoss 6.0.0

> jconsole service:jmx:rmi://localhost/jndi/rmi://localhost:1090/jmxconnector

works. If you replace `localhost` with your host address, it worked as well.

Note that I started JBoss using

> run.sh -c whatever --host=0.0.0.0

so that JBoss binds to *all* interfaces/addresses (instead of localhost only):

> --host=host_or_ip ...  Bind address for all JBoss services

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the run.sh to :

```
export JMX_ARGS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3000 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
java $JVM_ARGS -classpath $CLASSPATH $JMX_ARGS  org.hornetq.integration.bootstrap.HornetQBootstrapServer $FILENAME
```

then when hornetq starts you should see this in the log :

```
15:15:22,312 CONFIG [sun.management.jmxremote] JMX Connector ready at: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:3000/jmxrmi
```

on the client side you should be able to connect to the server with this :

```
val url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:3000/jmxrmi")
val connection = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, new java.util.HashMap())
def mbeanServer = connection.getMBeanServerConnection()
val objectName = new ObjectName("org.hornetq:module=Core,type=Server")
val serverInfo = mbeanServer.getMBeanInfo(objectName)
println(serverInfo.getDescription())
```